# How to getChildText() of a node with a namespace, when there are multiple namespaces in the XML?

Tags: java, xml, xpath, jdom

I want to use getChildText() to get text from a node that is a few levels deep.  There are two namespaces in the file.  The syntax below does not work and sets **textToGet** to **null**.

```
 String textToGet = root.getChildText("ns1:Customer/ns1:Address/ns1:Street/ns2:Streetname");
```

I know there is an alternative of first getting the Child Element, and then its Text, but I want to use a one-liner.

Also, would rather not chain getChild(), because some of the elements are not guaranteed to be in the file.

Answer (score 1):

You are not going to be able to make that a one-liner....

Consider using XPaths.... JDOM 2.x should help with that:

```
XPathExpression<String> xpe = XPathFactory.instance().compile(
    Filters.fstring(), "ns1:Customer/ns1:Address/ns1:Street/ns2:Streetname",
    null, namespace_ns1, namespace_ns2);
String textToGet = xpe.evaluateFirst(root);
```

(textToGet may be null)

Edit, the XPath expression above actually returns an element... you should add "/text()" to the end of the XPath, or change textToGet to be String (and the Filters too).

Rolf